# MySQL order of elements in `trigger after insert`

Tags: mysql, triggers

I need to create a trigger that takes a flat event source and transforms it into a row with start_time and end_time.

There are two systems and a job that communicates the data from one to another:

```
 ________            _________
|        |   Job    | Destiny |
| Source |  ----->  |         |
|________|   data   |_Trigger_|
```

Inside Destiny, there are two tables:

```
 ____________________              ________________________
|                    |   Trigger  |                        |
|  Flat event table  | <--------- |  Copy of source table  |
|____________________|            |________________________|
```

The following represents an example from the source:

```
|    datetime    | tagname | value |
  1/1/13 07:00       tag       1
  1/1/13 07:05       tag       0
  1/1/13 10:07       tag       1
  1/1/13 13:13       tag       0
```

And i need the data to look like:

```
|   id   |  start_time  |   end_time   |   duration  |   uptime  | reason
  event1   1/1/13 07:00   1/1/13 07:05        5             0       xxx
  event2   1/1/13 10:07   1/1/13 13:13       76            182      yxy
```

So far, I have created logic that finds the last event and updates it, and it has been  working fine, except for one small detail:  If the events occur really frequently, the system will create a bulk of inserts, and that bulk is being executed in weird orders.

If this is helpful somehow, this is a segment of the trigger I use to get the correct id: 
(For full code click [here](http://chopapp.com/#641y0q5o))

```
select delays.id,product_id,crew_id
into t_lastId, t_product_id,t_crew_id
from delays join line_reasons on delays.line_reason_id = line_reasons.id
where line_reasons.line = t_line order by delays.start_time desc limit 1;
```

I should also mention that as I can't create triggers on the main system, I created a job that will basically duplicate these values into an `events` table:

```
id |  event_timestamp  |  event_value  | event_attr... |
 1    1/1/13 07:00            1            'event started'...
 2    1/1/13 07:05            2            'event ended'...
```

My trigger is run on this `events` table.

An example showing how the bulk looks like and why the insert fails with my trigger:

```
 |      datetime      | tagname | value |
    1/1/13 07:40:10       tag       1
    1/1/13 07:41:05       tag       1
    1/1/13 07:40:45       tag       0
```

As you can see the bulk is not inserted in the correct chronological order, giving this output:

```
 |   id   |  start_time     |     end_time      |   duration  |   uptime  | reason
   event1   1/1/13 07:40:10    1/1/13 07:40:10          5             0       xxx
   event2   1/1/13 07:41:05    1/1/13 07:40:45         -20s          55s     yxy
```

**Update**

I can't see a reason anymore why should duration and uptime be a stored value inside my table. Having them calculated on the fly will over simplify a lot of work.

Comment: I have two systems, `source` and `destiny`, in the `source` i can't create triggers. I created a `job` on the `source` that every minute inserts data into my `destiny` table, from there i created a trigger that tries to flat the events into one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand very well, but

```
WHERE end_datetime > start_datetime
```

doesn't help you?

with this way you will not match equal nor negative times.

Comment: Ok that's a good idea, but what can i reinsert that record into the table?

Comment: And if you look carefully, the correct time between events it's not 55s, it's 20 seconds..

Comment: after removing the fields to calculations, this works perfectly.